# JS parallax effect / only usable for Images/Elements that are not positioned at the top

Tags: javascript, parallax

I'm currently trying to create a lightweight parallax effect in JS.
The only problem that i'm running into is, when i try to assign the effect to elements mid-document. Here's the current code:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('parallax'), function (v) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        let eTop = $('parallax').offset();
        let value = window.scrollY;
        v.style.top = value * .5 + 'px';
    });
});
```

If i now assign the 'parallax' class to objects below the top position they get weirdly transformed because their respective position is calculated using window.scollY resulting in heavily transformed positions.
I guess the best way to deal with it is to subtract the elements actual position on the document, right? And if so how to do it? (newbie here)

Thamks in advance!

Comment: (1) Your selector selects for an element with the tag name parallax not with the class, and (2) you shouldn’t be attaching a new scroll event listener to ever single element. Iterate through the elements in one single scroll event callback.

Comment: well how to do that?